# HTML incompatibility on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm really struggling to work out why my site isn't displaying on Chrome, the code's very simple and I can't imagine there's anything ambitious enough to disrupt it. I've tried with/without preloader and with/without replace on hover, but it still won't display anything but the top menu.

I know it's not great coding but it's been working fine on Firefox for years! I would really appreciate any help - someone with an eagle eye may be able to spot it immediately.

You can find the source at http://amysutton.com/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have a table in a table which has a height of 1%. I'm not very suprised it isn't working with a height like that.

Remove that attribute and you should be fine.

Also I suggest you get rid of that table layout sooner rather than later, those things are considdered a sin nowadays.

This is the offending line:

```
<table width="100%" height="1%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="sideIcons">
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, I really appreciate it. I know, I'm terrible - I've been stuck as a newb for over a decade.xxx

Comment: Glad I could help but don't forget to accept answers that helped you or you'll get diminishing returns on the answers of your questions :p